# Qlikview expression select value that has the latest date for reference line

Tags: date, expression, max, qlikview

I have a basic bar graph and i want to add a reference line expresion to it.

However when i add the line it is taking the wrong value.

Sample data

```
SaleDate   DaysToPay
01/02/2015 60
01/03/2015 60
01/06/2015 60
01/07/2015 30
```

As you can see the days to pay drops to 30 for the most recent date, this needs to be the value the reference line uses.

Currently the expression I have tried i:

```
=[DaysToPay]
```

Which gives the value of 60.

In SQL I would do the following, but this doesn't work in a QV expression for a reference line.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DaysToPay, MAX(SaleDate) AS MaxSaleDate
    FROM sales 
    GROUP BY DaysToPay) groupDays
ON s.DaysToPay = groupDays.DaysToPay
AND s.SaleDate = groupDays.MaxSaleDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is loaded in as a date field, you can force Qlik to use the value associated with the latest date in your reference line with:

```
=concat({$<SaleDate={"$(=max(SaleDate))"}>} DaysToPay)
```

I use the `concat` function above, however in the situation where there is only ever one record per day, the function is irrelevant as you will only ever have one value to concat. In a situation where you have multiple values per day, you'll need to decide what logic you want to use to keep one of the values, or aggregate them somehow (i.e. average).